# How do I browse the filesystem in Android using a third party component?

Tags: android, image, file, android-intent, file-manager

I have got a directory with loads of files within it.
Now, I want to open an application (a file manager | a image manager) by giving the folder path to it (e.g. /data/sdcard/DCIM/unbelievable_awesome_images/).

A file manager just has to browse to this simple directory, a image manager should automatically read out all the images within this folder and display as he whishes.

The main idea is to have an overview of all the included images within this directory and the ability to simple view it.

- Do you have any idea how to solve this using Intent's?
- Have you got another, better idea how to approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can send an intent to OIFileManager which will have to be installed for this to work http://openintents.org/en/filemanager.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("org.openintents.action.PICK_FILE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but I don't want users to install any additonal app. :/ It's not important that it does work EVERYWHERE, but it should work at most devices, thus, its just a feature; not a main advantage. Maybe I could check the package name of the "default file managers" of Samsung/HTC/Motorola and if one exists, start that one with the desired path. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to solve this. By the way, your intent is not providing information about the path to be opened, does it master telekinesis?^^

Comment: You can see the options for the intent by clicking the link. If you definitely need it to work on all devices you should probably bundle the code into your app and forget about using a quick-fix solution.